# Listview setonitemclicklistener

Tags: android, listview, dialog, onclick

I've looked up similar post regarding this question but they didn't solve my issue, so here it is.

I'm trying to set a setOnItemClickListener, for when I click on any item of my list I will open a dialog with the info (retrieve from the list) on the clicked list and more info. But i'm struggling to implement the setOnItemClickListener part.

I'm getting and error in line:  myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()){

```
package com.example.proyectoprueba;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;;

public class PlantillaChina extends ActionBarActivity{

     // DB Class to perform DB related operations
    DBController controller = new DBController(this);
    // Progress Dialog Object
    ProgressDialog prgDialog;
    HashMap<String, String> queryValues;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lista);
        Intent myIntent = getIntent();

        String value = myIntent.getStringExtra("key");
        TextView titulo=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.titulo);

     // Get Platos records from SQLite DB

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> platoList = controller.getAllEntremeses();
        if (value.equals("entremeses")){
            platoList = controller.getAllEntremeses();
            titulo.setText(value);
        }else if(value.equals("arroces y pasta")){
                platoList = controller.getAllArrocesyPasta();
                titulo.setText(value);
            }else if(value.equals("mar")){
                    platoList = controller.getAllMar();
                    titulo.setText(value);
                 }else if(value.equals("carnes")){       
                            platoList = controller.getAllCarnes();
                            titulo.setText(value);
                 }
        // If Platos exists in SQLite DB
        if (platoList.size() != 0) {
            // Set the Plato Array list in ListView
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(PlantillaChina.this, platoList, R.layout.itemlista, new String[] {
                            "platoId", "platoNombre", "platoDescripcion", "platoPrecio" }, new int[] {R.id.codigo, R.id.nombre, R.id.descripcion, R.id.precio });
            ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaplatos);
            myList.setAdapter(adapter);
            myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()){

        }
    }
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Which error? Can you post logcat?

Comment: Which error ? I guess NPE on your listView.

Comment: Step through the code and verify that "myList" is valid when you call setOnItemClickListener.

Comment: Thank for the comments!! It's solved. I forgot to put the logcat, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 It think you want something like this.

 myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int  
                               position, long id) 
        {
            // You have the position available here as well as the clicked view.
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thank worked! thank you very much! Now I would try to figure out how to the data from the listview

Answer (score 0):

You need to actual define the OntItemClickListener to do something.

First, the code you have doesn't make much sense. You want something like this:

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
    {
        // Your code here
    }
});
```

Basically you are creating your own OnItemClickListener class, and overriding the OnItemClick method. This callback will get called whenever an item in your list is clicked. You can do whatever processing you would like inside that function.